# How to slice an array to get only the last 2 numbers in that array - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm a newbie in javascript.
Please help me to solve this problem.

How to slice an array to get only the last 2 numbers in that array - JavaScript, like this:
[1234, 5432, 765764, 546542, 234, 5454] to [34, 32, 64, 42, 34, 54]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```js
const array = [1234, 5432, 765764, 546542, 234, 5454];
const arrayMap = array.map(x => x % 100);
console.log(arrayMap);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you could just use the modulus here to find the last two digits of each input number:

```js
var input = [1234, 5432, 765764, 546542, 234, 5454];
var output = [];
for (var i=0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    output.push(input[i] % 100);
}
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Slicing in javascript would be to get a sub array of the original array, what you're looking for is a transformation of the values.

The operation you need is to take the number and apply `% 100`. This will return the remainder from when dividing with 100, which becomes the last two digits.

In code this will look like:

```js
list = [11234, 5432, 765764, 546542, 234, 5454]
newList = list.map( (num) => { return num % 100 })
console.log(newList)
```